# How to correctly use a matrix (Eigen library) in my own class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, matrix, vector, eigen

I really tried to solve this problem and I have read a lot of QAs here on Stackoverflow but somehow nothing really helped.

I am trying to implement a Class with its own matrices and vectors from the Eigen library. I am using Code::Blocks with GNU GCC Compiler.

### Here is a simple example of what I mean, but it is not the exact code, because I am using more matrices and vectors and of other sizes (4x4 Matrices, 2x4 Matrices, 4x1 Vectors and 2x1 Vectors):

```
    class MYCLASS{
        private:

            VectorXd x;
            MatrixXd A;

        public:

            MYCLASS(double, double, double, double);
            double get_matval();

    };

    MYCLASS::MYCLASS(double deltaT, double q_var, double r1_var, double r2_var){

        x_m(0)=q_var;
        x_m(1)=r1_var;
        x_m(2)=r2_var;
        x_m(3)=0.0;

        A(0,0)= deltaT;
        A(0,1)= 0.0;
        A(1,0)= 0.0;
        A(1,1)= 0.0;

    }

    double MYCLASS::get_matval(){

        return A(0,0);

    }
```

### 1. When I create an object of MYCLASS, like this:

```
MYCLASS myobject(10, 0.5, 0.1, 0.75);
```

==> Compilation is good, but when it runs, then the program somehow crashes with the following exact description (keep in mind I have other matrices and vectors):

> Assertion failed: index >= 0 && index < size(), file
>   F:....../Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h, line 425
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact...
>
> Process returned 3 (0x3) execution time: 2.131 s

### 2. If I then put at the beginning of the constructor this:

```
    MYCLASS::MYCLASS(double deltaT, double q_var, double r1_var, double r2_var){

            VectorXd x(4);
            MatrixXd A(2,2);

            x_m(0)=q_var;
            x_m(1)=r1_var;

            ...and so on...
```

==> then when constructing the object ==> no error

==> but when I then want to access A(0,0) by using the function get_matval, like this:

```
MYCLASS myobject(10, 0.5, 0.1, 0.75);

double myvar = myobject.get_matval();
```

...it crashes again with the same error message.

Could you guys please help?

Comment: `VectorXd x(4);` creates a new local variable in your constructor that has no realtion to the `x` variable in your class.

Comment: Looks like you need to set the size before adding elements. Knowing nothing at all about the eigen library I expect that you can at least do that in your constructors initializer list.

Comment: Looking at the documentation there is a resize() function that will let you initialize the size also. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html

Comment: Hey I can't believe it but that really helped! I just had to resize the matrices and vectors at the beginning of the constructor! e.g. A.resize(2,2). That worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Even though you found a solution already, here is how to properly initialize (a limited number of) Eigen matrices:

```
MYCLASS::MYCLASS(double deltaT, double q_var, double r1_var, double r2_var)
                : x(4), A(2,2) { // use initializer list to construct x and A
    x << q_var, r1_var, r2_var, 0.0;
    A << deltaT, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I had 20 matrices? Is this the way to go even then? Would I have 20 matrices in my initializer list?

Comment: If you have a lot of matrices, you should consider storing them into a `std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd>`, instead. But initializing 20 variables in the initializer list is no problem (I don't know what the minimal number is, a standard complying compiler must support, though)